# Storm Cluster only starts when putting the nimbus IP in the supervisors

Tags: configuration, installation, cluster-computing, apache-storm

When creating a Storm cluster it only starts when placing the nimbus node running zookeeper in the Storm.yaml file under supervisor and nimbus.

For example:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "10.1.0.193"
  - "10.1.0.194"

nimbus.host: "10.1.0.193"
```

**Question**
Is this the correct method? It seems strange to have it classed as a supervisor and the nimbus host.

It seems to run fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is correct. Supervisor needs to know Zk and nimbus IP because at startup supervisor register at nimbus (via Zk). All communication between supervisor and nimbus goes through Zk (Zk itself doesn't know nimbus IP either). There is no direct communication involved (because of fault tolerance reasons).